# Finding Matches on Range with Duplicate Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following equations, which are helping me to return the column header title for the largest three values in a range, however, they do not work appropriately when there are multiple cells in the range with the same value. I am applying them to find the names of the groups for the largest three percentages within the range (they are applied in 3 cells consecutively):

```
=INDEX($DK$2:$EG$2,1,MATCH(MAX(DK3:EG3),DK3:EG3,0))

=INDEX($DK$2:$EG$2,1,MATCH(LARGE(DK3:EG3,2),DK3:EG3,0))

=INDEX($DK$2:$EG$2,1,MATCH(LARGE(DK3:EG3,3),DK3:EG3,0))
```

For Example. If the greatest two values are both 40% in the range, the first equation will return the name of the first cell to have the value of 40%. Then the second equation will skip over the first two largest values, since they are equal and return what may be the name pertaining to the third largest value among the array.

Any thoughts on how to fix this, so that I get the index matches of the top the values that simply Pareto dominate all others in the array?

Comment: How do you define Pareto dominated in the context of your data set? Once you have your definition, that is what must be captured in your formula logic

Comment: I guess I would say that I would take the top 3 values, considering that two of them may be repeats. Pareto dominates strictly means greater than or equal to.

Comment: My suggestion is to reflect your data to a separate (possibly hidden) worksheet and sort the header/values according to your criteria. Then pick off your top values from that list. You may by able to create a dynamic named range or something (perhaps transposed into columns). Without seeing your data as a specific example, it's difficult to give you any more detailed advice.